# Importing a MySql generated csv huge file in ORacle 10g

Tags: oracle, csv, data-import

I am trying to import a csv file of size 6 GB into oracle 10 g.
I have used oracle sql developer and Toad but both of them take a lot of time to import data.
Is there any more efficient and fast method of importing such a huge file into oracle.

Comment: Yes.  Create an external table and select into the target table.  Example - http://jackass.io/2009/04/15/oracle-external-tables-by-examples-%E2%80%A6-part-3/  Lots of tutorials on external tables.  You can also probably use sqlloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sqlloader or external table as already proposed. In case you really need fast load: drop and recreate after load indexes/constraints, alter table with no-logging option.